# Azure datafactory: Headers in REST dataset with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm currently building a datafactory that needs to be rolled out to a whole slew of tenants. So I've opted to write C# code to create all the datafactory artifacts using a configuration file.

I've got almost everything done. I just run into a snag when creating the REST stuff. I need to add Headers to a WebActivity and to a REST Dataset.
I've tried doing this using a string which resulted in every character in the string becoming a separate header.
I've tried doing this using the HeaderOption class which resulted in... well... nothing. Empty headers in the DataFactory.

What is the best way to go about this?

Example code for the WebActivity (I'm assuming that getting this to work will mean getting the Dataset to work as well);

```
                    new WebActivity
                    {
                        Name = config.TokenActionName,
                        Method = config.TokenMethod,
                        Url = config.TokenUrl,
                        Headers = config.TokenHeader,
                        Body = restBody
                    },
```

Where config.TokenHeader is either

`config.TokenHeader = "\"Content-Type\": \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\""`

or

`config.TokenHeader = new HeaderOption("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`